# How to split dates from weather data file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new in python and i would greatly appreciate some help.
I have data generated from a weather station(`rawdate`) in the format `2015-04-26 00:00:48` like this

```
Date,Ambient Temperature (C),Wind Speed (m/s)
2015-04-26 00:00:48,10.75,0.00
2015-04-26 00:01:48,10.81,0.43
2015-04-26 00:02:48,10.81,0.32
```

and i would like to split them into `year` `month` `day` `hour` and `minute`. My attempt so far is this:

```
for i in range(len(rawdate)):
    x=rawdate[1].split()
    date.append(x)
```

but it gives me a list full of empty lists. My target is to convert this into a list of lists (using the command `split`) where the new data will be stored into x in the form of `[date, time]`. Then i want to split further using split with "-" and ":". Can someone offer some advice?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what rawdate stores/is? Is it a list or a string? Does it contain multiple datetimes or just one?

Comment: Rawdate is just the name that i am using. This data is taken from a .txt file and it contains 7 rows of data from which the first is the date in the format that i posted. The file contains data in sequential lines for the entire day.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and adjust your question accordingly, so people can answer it more easily.

Comment: Also worth noting that .split() will split stuff by a particular character. It defaults to space, but you can supply a character like `split('-')`. In your case, to split by multiple characters at once, look into re.split() where you can tell it to split by space, comma and dash together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is clearly broken, because you are not using the loop in any way other than repeating the same operation on `rawdate[1]`,  `len(rawdate)` times.

It's possible that you meant `i` where you have `1`.

For this to make sense, your rawdate would have to be a list of strings (as suggested by @SuperBiasedMan)

Maybe something close to what you were after is like this:

```
>>> dates = []
>>> rawdates = ['2015-04-26 00:00:48', '2015-04-26 00:00:49']
>>> for i in range(len(rawdates)):
...   the_date = rawdates[i].split()
...   dates.append(the_date)
... 
>>> dates
[['2015-04-26', '00:00:48'], ['2015-04-26', '00:00:49']]
>>>
```

Use meaningful names always.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime

>>> str_date = '2015-04-26 00:00:48'
>>> datte = datetime.strptime(str_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') 
>>> t = datte.timetuple()
>>> y, m, d, h, min, sec, wd, yd, i = t
>>> y
2015
>>> m
4
>>> min 
0
>>> sec
48
```

Comment: `strptime()`, `timetuple()` : nice!

Answer (score -1):

`rawdate[1]` will always return a `0` cause `'2015...'[1] is 0`.

```
>>>a = '2015-04-26 00:00:48'
>>>print([date for date in [i for i in a.split(' ')][0].split('-')] + [time for time in [i for i in a.split(' ')][1].split(':')])
>>>['2015', '04', '26', '00', '00', '48']
```